# Determining file type from android terminal emulator

Tags: terminal, file-properties

I have a file of unknown type that does not display properly in es file explorer and I have no other app installed that can open it. Can I use the terminal emulator (or some other method?) To determine it's file type so as to google the extension and find an appropriate app?

Answer (score 0):

for find File Format, copy this file in Linux, then use this command:

> `file input`

i tried many commands for this in terminal(Android), and does not work.